# Unable to copy file from SharePoint different site document library with sp-pnp-js

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary, pnp-js, sharepoint-documents

I need to copy a file from one SharePoint online site document library to another SharePoint online document library under the same tenant.

I have used "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10" in my solution.

Below is my code snippet,

```
// let sourceFIleUrl = "https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/contoso1/Shared Documents/folder1/new-file.docx";
// let destinationFileUrl = "https://mytentant.sharepoint.com/contoso2/Shared Documents/folder2/new-file.docx";
    
// I have tried adding server relative url like below
    
let sourceFIleUrl = "/contoso1/Shared Documents/folder1/new-file.docx";
let destinationFileUrl = "/contoso2/Shared Documents/folder2/new-file.docx";
        
sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath(sourceFIleUrl).copyTo(destinationFileUrl, false).then((res) => {
    console.log("Files added", res);
}).catch((err) => { console.log("Error in copy file", err) });
```

With the use of the above code. If I try to copy documents in the same site document libraries then it is working correctly. But if I try to copy documents from one site to another site. It threw the below error,

"*Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl*"

Kindly note that, I have used "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10". So, there is no replacement for the copyTo command. If I replace copyTo with copyByPath then PnP throws an error while building the solution.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using server relative URLs of files/library instead of complete/absolute URL.

For example:

```
// sourceFIleUrl is a server-relative url of a existing file
const sourceFIleUrl = "/sites/contoso1/Shared Documents/test.docx";
// destinationUrl is a server-relative url of a new file
const destinationUrl = `/sites/contoso2/Shared Documents/new-file.docx`;

await sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath(sourceFIleUrl).copyByPath(destinationUrl, false, true);
```

**Documentation**: [copy file by path](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/#copy-by-path)

---

**Similar threads**:

1. [REST API error "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214750/rest-api-error-server-relative-urls-must-start-with-spweb-serverrelativeurl)
2. [GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl Rest API return Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/203179/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl-rest-api-return-serve.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,

I have updated my code as you suggested. Still, I have faced the same error. 

Kindly note that, I have used "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10". So, there is no replacement for copyTo command. If i replace copyTo with copyByPath then PnP throws an error.

Comment: I have tried with server relative URLs of files/library instead of complete/absolute URL but still, I have faced the same issue while performing this operation between two subsites of the root site. Please let me know your thoughts on the same.